# How to make 3 dimension vertical menu using CSS

Tags: html, css, menu

Looking for some ideas of vertical menus and found this example in picture. How to make it fold like that and look 3D?

Maybe anyone knows where and how to find real life example of similar menu with code? That website don't work anymore with that menu. Already tried.

Thanks

Example :

[image]

Comment: Ok, done it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to make use of **position: absolute** and **transform: skew** combination

***Stack Snippet***

```css
ul.menu {
  font: 13px Verdana;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

ul.menu>li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #808080c4;
  color: #fff;
}

ul.menu>li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  left: -40px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: grey;
  transform: skewY(30deg);
  transform-origin: right;
}

ul.menu>li:hover,
ul.menu>li:hover:before {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Menu One</li>
  <li>Menu Two</li>
  <li>Menu Three</li>
  <li>Menu Four</li>
  <li>Menu Five</li>
  <li>Menu Six</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes. This works for me but need little fix for submenus and then all will be fine.

Comment: @MārisL will you tell the  _**need little fix**_

Comment: Can't see how to add image in comment, so there is link http://i66.tinypic.com/htzktj.jpg

When submenu opens, how to change submenu color for Tops, Bottom, Footwear. If I change color for them, then color changes for Home, About and others

Comment: assign a class `submenu` to your submenu `<ul>` and use this class to change the colors of submenu elements like `.sumenu>li{color:red;}`

Comment: Did like this  ul.menu .submenu li { background-color: transparent; } and worked for me. Thanks